# How do I delete Airflow from Windows 11

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I installed Airflow with Docker on Windows 11 a while back. There is no Airflow folder in both of the Programs directories on my laptop.

I used a Revo Uninstaller to uninstall the program. This is apparently supposed to uninstall it through the logs.

I have an "airflow-docker" file on my Desktop with the dags,logs and plugins folders and the docker-compose yaml file.

How do I ensure the uninstalling has been successful?

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't install the software within the container on your host. If your `docker-compose.yml` has `volumes` defined, then those are just files, not "installed", and you can remove them, if you want.

Comment: I have something akin to " .:/sources " under " volumes: " . Just above volumes is ' user: "0:0" '

Comment: I don't know the file-layout of the Airflow container, but that'll mount the directory where the yaml file is into the container. Once the container starts, anything written into `/sources` will then be "copied" into the host, which is why you see the files/folders you mentioned. This does not mean anything related to Airflow is "installed"

Comment: So I can just delete airflow-docker folder I created with the dags,logs and plugins folders? Along with the docker-compose yaml file? An issue in that folder is the "logs" subfolder is active. Having logged it's most recent subfolder labelled with today's date. With folders going back to everyday since May 9th of this year

Comment: @OneCricketeer The instructions are actually listed in the manual https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#cleaning-up-the-environment it's just `rm -rf '<DIRECTORY>'`